# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail ---> Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sendgrid

I'm using windows server R2, .Net 4.5, WCF rest services and SendGrid to send email. I get the following exception when trying to send emails having multiple attachments.

My Total attachments size is always less than 25MB and maximum of 5 attachments for an email. I get the below exception when attaching a one file with 24MB or multiple files having 100KB. I'm receiving this is totally random. Sometime it goes, most of the time I get this exception

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Mime.EightBitStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Mime.BaseWriter.Flush(MultiAsyncResult multiResult)
   at System.Net.Mime.MimeWriter.Close()
   at System.Net.Mime.MimeMultiPart.Send(BaseWriter writer, Boolean allowUnicode)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

I found this https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/851 but it does not gives a solution. I'm not even sure that my exception is related to SendGrid.

Comment: Do it fail every time you send same message?  You may have a virus checker that is checking contents of message and closing when unacceptable data is being emailed.  It may be a timeout.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Or poor/faulty communications

Comment: @jdweng for couple of attachments it is failing. So total size was 1.5MB for 5 files i was trying now. I don't get the error if the total attachment size is less than 100KB.

Comment: @bradbury9 what do you meant by poor/fault communication?

Comment: I like testing communications using PING with large messages : ping -t -l 65500 IP.  The error sounds like a virus checker in combination with the timeout.  If checker is delaying message a timeout may be occurring.

Comment: @jdweng Who would be doing the virus checking? does SendGrid has its own virus checker? or someone else is doing the virus checking? Is there a place I can look at?  I'm confused because SendGrid v3 allows maximum of 10MB and v2 allows 7MB. I'm trying to upload 1.5MB and failling. 1.4MB no exception and email sends. see [https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/attachments-with-digioh](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/attachments-with-digioh)